# Многоцветное кольцо-контур для кнопки на android

Tags: java, android, xml

Доброго времени суток.

Я создаю приложение-ежедневник и хочу реализовать следующую функциональность:

Каждый элемент календаря [день] на экране пользователя имеет свой цветовой окрас (кольцо вокруг даты). Этот окрас будет зависеть от того, какие метки были добавлены на карточку того или иного дня.
Изначально цвет кольца серый и он сможет включать до 4х цветов. Цвета должны распределяться по кольцу согласно картинке ниже.
При этом я могу изменять метки дня и цвета тоже будут меняться.

Я пытался сделать это с помощью Drawble.Shape, но, видимо, теми средствами нельзя покрасить 1 эллипс сразу в 4 цвета без всякого градиента.
Что я могу использовать для достижения своей цели?

Спасибо
[image: Figma?.. Paint)]

Comment: Тут надо бы кастомную вьюху с рисованием того что нужно на канвасе. Однако, если не может быть вариантов любого расположения рамки и они всегда по четвертям разбито, то можно, вроде, так сверстать чтобы было как вам нужно. Но это будет, пожалуй, сложнее и менее гибко чем рисование на канвасе

Comment: Как писали выше - custom view или поищи готовые решения, например что то вроде этого https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6599. Ну и не к делу совет - с закруглением cardView мне кажется ты перебарщиваешь,а цветовую палитру можно тут подобрать например - https://coolors.co/palettes/trending .